# Can I stop D6's email sending to blocked users?

Tags: 7

I have a few actions. They send email to authors.
The problem is, I don't want emails to be sent if the user is blocked.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

ps: I couldn't create a tag on drupal.stackexchange.com . So tagging this custom-module for posting sake.

Comment: Are you using rules for this? If so you should be able to add a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [hook_mail_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/6) to check the mail before it's send and filter it depending on your conditions.